# unable to connect to wifi

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit

My Ubuntu laptop cannot connect to WiFi automatically. I have to restart my laptop for more than one time to connect to WiFi.what could be the problem?

Comment: Please provide more information. What type of wireless card you are using, the exact model and PCI.ID information along with anything else that can help, including steps you have tried to get it working.